# make input label stay up when the input in not focus

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a style component with input and label. the label goes up when it's focus and moves down when it's unfocused.

how can I make the label stay up when there a value in the input or when I unfocusedthe input?

my code :

```
        import React from "react";
        import styled from "styled-components";
        
        const Wrapper = styled.div`
          position: relative;
        `;
        
        const Input = styled.input`
          font-size: 18px;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
          display: block;
          width: 300px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
          &:focus {
            outline: none;
          }
        `;
        
        const Label = styled.label`
          color: #999;
          font-size: 18px;
          font-weight: normal;
          position: absolute;
          pointer-events: none;
          left: 5px;
          top: 10px;
          transition: 0.2s ease all;
          input:focus ~ &,
          input:not(:placeholder-shown).input:not(:focus) ~ .label {
          top: -20px;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: #5264ae;
      }
`;
        
        const FloatingInput = () => (
          <Wrapper>
            <Input />
            <Label>First Name</Label>
          </Wrapper>
        );
        
        export default FloatingInput;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `required` attribute to the `input` and add a `input:valid ~ &` selector for the label. When the input has *some* value it will become "valid" and the CSS selector will pick that up and apply the same style as when its focused.

```
const Input = styled.input.attrs(() => ({
  required: true,
}))`
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

const Label = styled.label`
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  input:focus ~ &,
  input:not(:placeholder-shown).input:not(:focus) ~ .label,
  input:valid ~ & {
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5264ae;
  }
`;

const FloatingInput = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Input />
    <Label>First Name</Label>
  </Wrapper>
);
```

[image: Edit make-input-label-stay-up-when-the-input-in-not-focus]

If you are wanting to toggle the "focused" style and make it stick once focused you'll need a bit of React state to hold the triggered state.

```
const Input = styled.input`
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

const focusCSS = css`
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264ae;
`;

const Label = styled.label`
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  input:focus ~ &,
  input:not(:placeholder-shown).input:not(:focus) ~ .label {
    ${focusCSS}
  }
  ${({ focused }) => focused && focusCSS}
`;

const FloatingInput = () => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Input onFocus={() => setFocused(true)} />
      <Label focused={focused}>First Name</Label>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit make-input-label-stay-up-when-the-input-in-not-focus (forked)]

Comment: thank u for the answer. but each input and label that I add the label are display over each other.

Comment: how can i set each label for his own input?

Comment: @yanirmidler Are you asking how to pass a label to display instead of using the hardcoded `"First Name"`? You could just expose a `label` prop on `FloatingInput`, like `<FloatingInput label="First Name" />` or render it as the `children` prop, like `<FloatingInput>First Name</FloatingInput>`, and then just render this passed prop value within the `Label` component.